# how to display multi table data in one page like facebook news feed

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

How can I display multi table data in one page like the facebook news feed?

example tables /event,task/

I want to sort by them by datetime with the newest at the top. 
I can do it by php, but I need the mysql way.

```
  event.row1  
  task.row1
  event.row2  
  task.row2
  event.row3  
  task.row3
   ... 
  older
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via MySQL

```
SELECT `AllData`.`id`, `AllData`.`date`
FROM
((SELECT `id`, `date` FROM `Events`)
UNION
(SELECT `id, `name` FROM `Tasks`)) `AllData`
ORDER BY `AllData`.`date`
```

You must have the same fields names to make the use, use `AS` to rename fields the same way in the request

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a virtual table pulling in all the required bits of the other tables?

Use `CREATE VIEW` syntax.